# How To create a React Native app to receive stress data from Xiaomi Band 7

Tags: react-native, android-bluetooth

"I want to create an application using React Native to fetch stress data from Xiaomi Band 7 via Bluetooth. I would like to know the detailed steps and if possible, provide me with sample code."

like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/791TT.jpg)